# Facebook OAuth no longer functioning

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I had a script that was working perfectly up until a couple of hours ago. This script authorizes a user, checks to see if the user is logged in, and inserts data into my database.
As of now, it fails to both identify a user or insert any data. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
  <!--
       #apDiv1 {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:198px;
z-index:1;
left: 757px;
top: 18px;
    }
       -->
      </style>
     <div id="apDiv1"><img src="../Downloads/tree06_small.png" width="188" height="250"     alt="" /></div>
    <?php
     require ("santatree/facebook.php");
       include('login.php');
       $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'id',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        ));


      $db_select=mysql_select_db($db_database); 
     if (!$db_select) 
     { 
     die ("Impossible Function". mysql_error());
       } 


     $user = $facebook->getUser();
     if ($user) {

     try {
       // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
         $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
       } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    if ($user) {

     $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
      $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
       $friendsData = $friends['data'];

       $User = $user['data']; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($friendsData); $i++)
    {
     $friend = $friendsData[$i];
       echo $friend['name'] . ", ";
      echo $friend['id']; 
        echo $user['id'];
       $sq1 = "INSERT into tbl_Friends (Name, FriendID, Access_ID) VALUES                  ('".$friend['name']."', '" .$friend['id']."', '".$user_profile['id']."')";
          error_log($e);
        $user = null;
            }
       }
         mysql_query($sq1); 

     }         
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();


      } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

    }

      $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_276853929000834_access_token'];
      if (!$access_token) {
      echo '<script>';
       echo 'top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'";';
         echo '</script>';
     } else {
         // ------ Create Drop Down Name List from Friends Table ------

        $myuserid = $user_profile['id'];
       echo "<html>";
         echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'       action='uploadpicture1.php' name='Giftgiver'>";
      $result= @mysql_query("select Friend_ID, tbl_Friends.Name from tbl_Friends inner              join tbl_Users on tbl_Friends.Access_ID=tbl_Users.Access_ID where tbl_Friends.Access_ID =         $myuserid"); 
      print "<p> Select a Friend: \n";
    print "<Select name=\"Friend_ID\">\n";
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $Friend_ID=$row['Friend_ID'];
     $Name =$row['Name'];
       print "<option value=$Friend_ID>$Name \n";
       }
          print "</select>\n";
         print "</p>\n";
        echo "Choose a gift!";
        echo "<input type='file' name='GiftChoice' value='1'>";

         }
         echo "</form>"; 
         echo "</html>";
          ?>
```

Comment: No one has an answer? Please help if possible.

Comment: what is your facebook php-sdk version?

Comment: SDK-3 is the version of the sdk I use

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make you you have updated to Facebook's oAuth 2.0?
All FB apps and apps using the FB api are required to upgrade to oAuth 2.0 by October 1st, 2011.